# In Django, what is the easiest way to make only the author edit/remove a posting?

Tags: django, authorization

In Django, I have a Post model that users can post a message. In views.py, how to make only the original author of the posting can edit or remove it?

```
@login_required
def edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
```

Comment: Can you please add your `Post` model?

Answer (score 2):

You could add the `user` as a filter too:

```
@login_required
def edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk, author=request.user)
```

`author` is the field on the `Post` model corresponding to the user. If your field is named something else you can use that here.

This will raise `HTTP-404` error if there is no `Post` with id `pk` with the `author` being the user who is requesting the page.

Answer (score 0):

`get_or_create()`, aside from accepting the model class, also accepts a queryset. So, what you can do is pass the queryset of all of the user's post.

I think the simplest way you can achieve this, is by doing something like

```
@login_required
def edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(request.user.posts.all(), pk=pk)
```